# Logout using FeathersJS REST API

Tags: rest, feathersjs, feathers-authentication

Using freshly generated FeathersJS application (local auth), I am doing following REST api calls with following behaviour:

1. GET /users - it FAILS with not-authorized
2. POST /authentication with username and password - successful
3. GET /users - it SUCCEEDS and returns list of users
4. DELETE /authentication - returns auth object, no error messages
   (and on server side logout event is generated)
5. GET /users - it SUCCEEDS and returns list of users

expected result from my side is that on step 5 I would get not-authorized error, as JWT token would be expired after logout on server side.

what am I doing wrong? how can I logout user properly using just REST api, so token would be invalidated? or authentication is meant to be used only in conjunction with FeathersJS client libraries?

p.s. I am trying out FeathersJS as a potential solution for backend REST API for my Flutter app. Hence I am interested only in server side implementation of FeathersJS.

Comment: Feathers auth is NOT a session based thing, it uses a client-side token.  Calling DELETE /authentication exists so that you could, in your own code, take actions to implement a server-side logout (e.g. blacklisting the current token), but it is not built-in.  If the client still has the auth token then it will continue to work until its expiration (embedded in the JWT)

Comment: I am not saying it is a session based thing. Just in my experience working with express.js backends, JWT token us invalidated on server side upon logout

Comment: Feathers does not do that automatically.  The remove hook is there so you can wire up your own logic to handle the server-side invalidation/tracking of the issued tokens, but it is not a built-in capability.

Comment: maybe can you point to the docs or example describing how to use the hook to remove or invalidate the token? I couldn't find anything that would describe manipulation with the tokens server side

Comment: There's nothing built-in. You'd create an `after` hook on the `remove` method of the authentication service, and take action on the token there (which should be in `params.authentication.payload` IIRC)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FeathersJS is stateless. So, in your client, just set your access token to null.

Comment: if i might ask - how can it be stateless if FeathersJS has to verify token of each client, then those tokens need to be stored somehow within FeathersJS? Which is a state?

Comment: I suggest looking up how JSON Web Tokens work. Yes, Feathers has to verify tokens. But it does so by serializing the data in the token and signing it using its secret before giving it back to you (the access token you get back). In subsequent requests, you send Feathers the access token which has all the data encoded on it. Feathers then verifies the data by checking the token you sent. No actual verification info (aside from the secret) is saved on the server. Hence no “state” is saved on the server. Hence, Feathers, like all other REST APIs is stateless.

Comment: @MartinsUntals Here’s a pretty good video that explains how JWT works, and how it compares to sessions, which is where I think your confusion is coming from. https://youtu.be/7Q17ubqLfaM Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I use socketio client. I normally logout users by calling app.logout() then clearing the localStorage item "feathers-jwt" just to be sure. follow this https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/client/rest.html#feathersjs-rest-client to read on how you can configure a REST client. hope it helps